# How to disable highlight when writing on EditText?

Tags: android, text, colors, android-edittext, highlight

I'm trying to change the color or disable the highlight of the text when writing on my [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html).

- How can I do that?
- How can I set rounded borders to the highlight?

I want to do that becouse, when I start writing on my EditText the highlight overlap the rounded corners of my EditText, and it looks bad.

Code for background color and corner rounded of my EditText:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">    
<corners android:radius="5dp" />
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/> 

</shape>
```

Code of my edittext:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextUsuario"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/propertieseditextlogin"
        android:ems="10" >
<requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

There are 2 examples of my problem:

- [Image - Gray highlight](http://imageshack.com/a/img854/573/izhy.png)
- [Image - Overlap rounded corners](http://imageshack.com/a/img585/4950/ymp7.png)

Comment: Hello, to remove Overlap rounded corners use padding. android:padding="1dp" // or u can increase as your need

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution of your [second problem](http://imageshack.com/a/img585/4950/ymp7.png)

Give **padding** to your EditText

Example:-

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextUsuario"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/propertieseditextlogin"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:ems="10" >
<requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Comment: @ParkEunNeul : Its a drawable .

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this attribute to your editText to disable highlighting.

```
android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled="false"
```

You can create highlight with rounded corners programmatically by creating custom View extending edit text, but that's really lot of work.
Also have a look for material design, with this library you can implement edit text with rounded corners pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the highlight of the edittext, you can just write following.

```
android:background="#00000000"
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the editext a padding using android:padding or set the background attribute to white